# Can't open the wordpress admin interface

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I use plesk and I have a site in wordpress.

I tried to make a change to the file **functions.php** which I found from **Appereance -> Editor** according to this [instructions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/) from this section Enqueuing Scripts and Styles #

I went to the end of file and added this code line form [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-keep-accordions-open-2/)

```
(function($) {
  $(function() {
    $( '.fl-accordion-button' ).trigger( 'click' );
  });
})(jQuery);
```

I pressed update and it tried to loaded it shows this error:

> This page isn’t working
>
> thenameaddressofmysite.com is currently unable to handle this request.
>
> HTTP ERROR 500

The problem is that I can't open the backend of wordpress and when I browse my site it has the same message.

Why this happened? How can I fix it? Can I find anywhere functions.php in plesk in httpdocs where httpdocs is the file which contains all the content?

Comment: A 500 error means somewhere on your server there's a very helpful error message in a log file. Go find it and read it.

Comment: @ceejayoz I use plesk and I don't where to find the error. I know only know that httpdocs contains the content but I don't know where to find the file

Comment: Then ask your host or whoever set up Plesk. Or Google where Plesk keeps log files.

Comment: Did you actually follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#scripts)? Or did you just see `functions.php` mentioned and dump your code right in there?

Comment: @PatrickQ unfortunately I made the second dummy thing. I when in backend of wordpress Appereance -> editor and found the functions.php and copy/paste the code and when I pressed the update this happended. It was a big fault my I try to find if I can find the file in httpdocs file in order to open and fix it. Do you believe is it possible?

Comment: Ok I found the answer. In plesk the httpdocs/wp-content/themes/bridge (bridge) is the theme I use and there is the functions.php so I edit it (removed the code I added) and know it is fine

Answer (score 0):

You've broken the PHP code of the page. Remove your hack and it will work properly.

Answer (score -1):

In plesk the httpdocs/wp-content/themes/bridge (bridge) is the theme I use and there is the functions.php so I edit it (removed the code I added) and know it is fine – Dikonstans 4 mins ago   edit